# C# ,Windows Service authorization, loosing token from header when making a request

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, token

When I try to make an authorization with .net windows service I get 404 Unauthorized, supposing because of the missing token, had the same problem when was doing the request from Postman, solution was to check this **Follow Authorization header** from settings, how can I reproduce that in c# code
this are my methods:

```
private string GeToken()
{
    var client = new RestClient("url");

    var restRequest = new RestRequest();
    restRequest.AddParameter("grant_type", "grant_type");
    restRequest.AddParameter("client_id", "client_id");
    restRequest.AddParameter("client_secret", "cliend_secred");
    restRequest.AddParameter("username", "username");
    restRequest.AddParameter("password", "password");
    restRequest.Method = Method.POST;
    var token = "Bearer " + (string)JObject.Parse(client.Execute(restRequest).Content).SelectToken("access_token");
    return token;
}
```

*The token is getting right every time,*

```
public void GetSoapResponse()
{
    var requestUrl = "url";
    var client = new RestClient(requestUrl);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", GeToken());
    IRestResponse soapModel = client.Execute(request);
}
```

Here in soapModel, I get 404 Unauthorized